# Can I charge for loss of interest?

Tags: halacha, lending-interest-ribbis

If I incur some transaction fee for giving a loan and pass it on to the borrower, I don't think it would be ribbis<sup>[citation needed]</sup> because it's not time-based and I don't gain from it.

But what if I'm also losing interest by withdrawing or liquidating the funds? Could I charge the borrower to recoup my losses or is it considered like I'm profiting from the loan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R Yisroel Reisman answers your question in his book [The laws of ribbis](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899061269.html), p. 81 and brings some granularity to the answer depending on the type of loss. **In a nutshell**

- **losses due to lost earnings or potential interest cannot be passed on and would be *ribbit***
- **losses due to penalties in principal or already earned interest can be passed on and are not *ribbit*.**

> If the lender has money which is earning interest in the bank and he
> withdraws this money to lend it to a friend, he may not be reimbursed
> for the lost earnings.
>
> [Sometimes when funds placed at fixed term] are withdrawn early, the
> depositor is assessed a penalty. If the depositor withdraws funds
> prematurely, solely because he wishes to lend this money, he would
> want the borrower to reimburse him for this penalty.
>
> Whether he may do so depends on the type of penalty which is incurred.
> If the penalty involves a loss of part of the principal which was
> deposited, the borrower may reimburse the lender for the loss!
>
> Often, the penalty involves only a loss of interest which the account
> had earned. For example, the penalty might call for the interest rate
> to be reduced, resulting in a loss of revenue for the depositor.
> Another common form of penalty is the forfeiture of thirty days
> interest.
>
> In these cases, reimbursement of the penalty is permitted only if the
> depositor was already in legal possession of the interest revenue,
> which is now taken from him as a penalty. When the depositor does not
> yet have the right to withdraw the interest, these funds have
> technically not actually come into his possession. Since this interest
> is not yet his, the penalty is actually a loss of potential revenue,
> which may not be reimbursed.